CreateML is not available when building for iOS Simulator
I am receiving the error CreateML is not available when building for iOS Simulator. Consider using `#if canImport(CreateML)` to conditionally import this framework.  which is preventing me from using previews. The code works fine whenever actually ran on a device but this is making developing new views a pain. I have tried using #if canImport(CreateML) but that causes more errors related to the createML code not being able to be recognized. I've also looked at the Dev forums and tried excluding the simulator architecture but nothing has worked yet. If someone could provide some feedback about how to get this error to go away so I am able to use the preview of another view it would be much appreciated.

Can you show the attempt at using #canImport? You should surround all your code that has to do with CreateML with that. And if your previews depend on CreateML, then tough luck - you can't use Previews.
